# When does the variance of a consistent estimator go to zero?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, statistical-inference

I came across the following statement (marked as *true*) in multiple-choice section of an old exam:

> The variance of a consistent estimator goes to zero with the growing sample size.

As far as I can tell, it can be translated as

> Convergence in probability to a constant implies convergence in $L^2$.

Which is clearly false.

Is there a way to repair the statement? I mean maybe the professor forgot to mention some additional assumption typical for the context. (E.g. how convergence in probability and uniform integrability together imply $L^1$ convergence, but it seems to be irrelevant for the above statement.)

Answer (score 2):

There are different concepts of consistency, knitted to different convergence concepts. You have almost-sure consistency, consistency in probability (defined by convergence in probability), $L^2$-consistency, and so on.

```
EDIT
```

The claim is not true, using the definition by convergence in probability. Maybe it is true by some stronger definition. I will give a (somewhat artificial) counterexample: Let
$$
   \hat{\theta}_n = \begin{cases} \theta ~~\text{with probability $\frac{n-1}{n}$}\\   \theta+n ~~ \text{with probability $\frac1n$} \end{cases}
$$
then we have convergence in probability, but also $E(\hat{\theta}_n-\theta)^2 = 0\cdot \frac{n-1}{n} + n^2\cdot \frac1n=n \rightarrow \infty$
disproving the claim.

Comment: But convergence in probability is exactly what I had in mind. Could you elaborate why is the cited claim true?

Comment: I corrected the answer

Comment: A slighly less artificial example would be an estimator with a Cauchy density, centered on the mean and which width (scale) tends to zero as $n \to \infty$. This would be a consistent estimator, however its variance is infinite for all $n$. What it's true is that almost all estimators in practice converge also in $L^2$, so many people (including some teachers) believe that vanishing variance is necessary for consistency, but that's wrong, it's just sufficient (together with asymptotic unbiasedness).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old post, but based on the other answer I wanted to give a slightly less artificial example I thought.

Consider the independent sample $$X_1, ..., X_n \sim Ber(p)$$

where $p \in (1/3, 2/3)$. Let $m = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$. Now create the following variables

$$Z = \prod_{i=1}^m X_i$$
$$Y = \frac{1}{n-m} \sum_{i=m+1}^n X_i$$

So basically, $Z \sim Ber(p^m)$ and is independent of $Y$ which is just the average of the remaining variables.

Consider the following estimator for $p$:

$$T = Y \cdot (1-Z) + Z \cdot 10^m$$

It is not hard to show that $T$ is actually consistent, since $Y$ converges in probability to $p$, and the probability that $\{T=Y\}$ (i.e: $Z=0$) goes to $1$.

On the other hand, we have

$$E(T) = p \cdot (1-p^m) + p^m \cdot 10^m \rightarrow \infty \hspace{1 cm} \text{ as } \hspace{0.5 cm} m \rightarrow \infty$$

since the first term goes to $p$ and the second term goes to infinity since we have that $10p>10/3$ because $p \in (1/3, 2/3)$.

Now, using Chebyshev inequality you can actually check that the variance of $T$ can't go to $0$. Just fix $K > 0$, and pick $n$ such that $E(T)>K+1$. Notice that whenever $\{Z=0\}$ we have that $\{T \in [0, 1]\}$, and therefore $|E(T)-T| \geq |E(T)-1| > K$. So $$P(\{|E(T)-T| > K\}) \geq P(Z=0) = 1-p^m \rightarrow 1$$

And therefore, Chebyshev inequality forbids $Var(T)$ from going to $0$.

Also, you can actually remove the hypothesis that $p \in (1/3, 2/3)$ if we just pick something faster for the term multiplying $Z$ in the expression of $T$. So considering something like $T = Y \cdot (1-Z) + Z \cdot 10^{10^m}$ should make the trick, and now the argument works for $p \in (0, 1)$.

This example is strongly based on [kjetil b halvorsen answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1221375/1279627), with subtle changes to make it less artificial.