# How to Make This Estimator Unbiased?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Could someone clarify if I'm interpreting this question correctly?

As the sample size increases and approaches infinity, then the expected value of the estimator would approach $0.$ The estimator is biased because $θ$ is not equal to $θ/n.$

But, if $n = 1,$ then wouldn't the expected value${} = θ$? Is this how the statistician's estimator would become unbiased?

Clarification appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We don't have to take limit of $n$ to $\infty$, currently we have

$$\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}]=\frac{\theta}{n}$$

We want to find $k$ such that

$$\mathbb{E}[k\hat{\theta}]=\frac{k\theta}{n}=\theta$$

Can you solve for $k$?

Comment: So that would solve for k = n?

Comment: yup, can you an unbiased estimator $\tilde{\theta}$ such that $\mathbb{E}[\tilde{\theta}]=\theta$ now?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be any number =/= 0? Unless k represents something specifically?

Comment: i thought you have conclude that $k=n$, that is $\mathbb{E}[k\hat{\theta}]=\theta$. can you find $\tilde{\theta}$ such that  $\mathbb{E}[\tilde{\theta}]=\theta$?

Comment: I think I just don't understand what the k represents in this. Is k - n the new estimator?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[n \hat{\theta}]=\theta$, the adjusted estimator is $n\hat{\theta}$.

Comment: In that case, if I wanted V(nθ^), would it be $$n^2σ^2/(n-1)?$$

Comment: $$V(n \hat{\theta})=n^2 V(\hat{\theta})=\frac{n^3\sigma^2}{n-1}$$

Comment: Thanks. This means that the amended estimator is unbiased but not consistent doesn't it? Because increasing n in the new variance in your last post, the variance increases with n?

Comment: I don't think the variance has anything to do with consistency.

Comment: My understanding is that the consistency increases if the bias falls and variance approaches 0 as n rises. But, the variance in your earlier post for the new estimator increases when n increases, meaning the new estimator might be unbiased, but it's inconsistent?

Comment: perhaps we are using different definition. does your definition mention anything about variance? [possibly relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1221331/306553)

Comment: Yes it does, i.e. the variance needs to approach 0 as n increases. I posted a similar question to this that you might be able to help with on this site, just slightly altered.